# Emacs with 24bit terminal support on FreeBSD

Tags: ssh, terminal, freebsd, emacs, terminfo

I'm trying to enable 24bit support on the terminal (via SSH) on my FreeBSD 12 installation without success.
I tried to create a terminfo file with the contents:

```
xterm-24bit|xterm with 24-bit direct color mode,
   use=xterm-256color,
   sitm=\E[3m,
   ritm=\E[23m,
   setb24=\E[48;2;%p1%{65536}%/%d;%p1%{256}%/%{255}%&%d;%p1%{255}%&%dm,
   setf24=\E[38;2;%p1%{65536}%/%d;%p1%{256}%/%{255}%&%d;%p1%{255}%&%dm,
```

And then executed the command (after installing ncurses):

```
$ tic -x -o ~/.terminfo xterm-24bit.terminfo
```

But when trying to run emacs, I get:

```
emacs: Cannot open terminfo database file
```

So, I tried to use `infocmp -Cr` to generate a termcap version and updated the db running:

```
# cap_mkdb /usr/share/misc/termcap
```

That almost worked, the emacs opens but black and white only :(

My terminal does support 24bit color and I use this mode via ssh on my other Linux machines.
Does anybody uses 24 bit terminals on FreeBSD?

Comment: I do.  I use the one that I wrote.  (-:  That really should _not_ be the question here.  You actually have three questions that this should ask: what needs to be done in the terminal database, what terminal database it in fact needs to be done in, and how to get emacs to recognize that.

Comment: It would only work if emacs is linked to an ncurses library using terminfo.  But the FreeBSD emacs package links to the system ncurses, which is configured to use only termcap.  You could configure/compile emacs yourself, but this group is of little use for advice on that sort of thing.

Comment: @ThomasDickey, I have compiled mine, but didn't know about linking to another ncurses library. I'll do some research about it. Thanks!

Comment: You might be able to use the ncurses *port*; I checked the *system* library by **`strings`**, looking for **`terminfo`**.

Comment: Are you going to fix your question to ask the right thing?  It's currently asking about something that you yourself are not even doing.  Your 24-bit colour terminal is running on _some other_ operating system, after all.

Comment: Recompiling the ncurses changing some flags (like removing --enable-termcap) and recompiling emacs only with --without-x flag did the trick!
Thank you very much @ThomasDickey!

Comment: no problem ([report bugs](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#report_bugs))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recompiled the ncurses with --disable-termcap;
Then recompiled emacs directly from the tarball (not from ports)
That worked as expected.
Thanks, @ThomasDickey for showing me a path to follow :)

Answer (score 2):

I have followed @Rafael Gil suggestions to recompile emacs, however, I have used the ports collection for both ncurses and emacs. For the benefit of those who might be still looking for a solution to this issue, this is what worked for me:

- Fetched and extracted the ports collection as usual `portsnap fetch extract` etc
- In `/usr/ports/devel/ncurses` manually edited its Makefile, line 23 that defines `CONFIGURE_ARGS` changing the hardcoded `--enable-termcap` to `--disable-termcap` as this was not a directly configurable option
- `make install` then `make clean`
- Using `/usr/ports/editors/emacs` compiled and installed emacs without X11 using `make FLAVOR=nox install` then `make clean`
- I found it necessary to add the compiled xterm-24bit terminfo file to the shared *system* one, rather than the user home directory—utilities including emacs where not seeing the definition in the home directory. In other words I had to use `sudo tic -x -s xterm-24bit.terminfo` which writes the entries to `/usr/local/share/misc/terminfo.db` on my FreeBSD 12.1.
- To launch it I have an alias to `env TERM=xterm-24bit emacsclient`, and I have installed the same terminfo using `tic` as at the top of this question.

It works, and I now have 24bit color, so I can use the solarized-dark and light themes in a remote FreeBSD shell session via ssh from iTerm on macOS.

I wonder if there is an easier solution to all of this—I do not fancy recompiling it all at every update etc. Any comments or suggestions would be much appreciated. BY the way, this is all related to [this Github issue related to the solarized theme](https://github.com/bbatsov/solarized-emacs/issues/18).